# position: relative but siblings thinking the element doesn't exist

Tags: css, css-position

I'm creating a tooltip. My problem is that when the tooltip appears, the siblings move, unlike `position: absolute`. I can't use an absolute position because that positions the tooltip relative to the browser window, and not it's original position.

HTML

```
<p class="tooltip-anchor">Hover me</p>
<span class="tooltip">Hello!</span>
```

CSS

```
.tooltip-anchor:hover + .tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    padding: 0.25em;
}
```

I made a [demo](https://codepen.io/sucker/pen/axxmwE?editors=1100) on Code Pen.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your question.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I didn't know that. I added some code, is it okay now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whit some modes to your code you can obtaine what do you want.
If you insert your span into the p tag you can set a position:absolute to the span (and position relative to it's container) and then modify it's position as you want.

> Position absolute: The element is removed from the normal document
> flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It
> is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any;
> otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its
> final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and
> left.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tooltip-anchor {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* modified */

.tooltip-anchor:hover .tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  /* modified */
  left: -40px;
  /* modify for center */
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  padding: 0.25em;
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size: 17px;">A simple tooltip. CSS is wonderful, may I say.</p>

<p class="tooltip-anchor">Hover me <span class="tooltip">Hello!</span></p>

<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: If this answer helps you , you can accept, or, if you need, you can ask more help